# Implement Mobile Device Management for Xamarin Forms code to capture the policy sent via the MDM

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, mdm

I am working in Xamarin Forms and I have a requirement from Enterprise clients that use MDM that they need to push a serverconnection to the App so that all users have the URL for the app end point.

My Xamarin Forms app is built to iOS and Android.
How do I code this into both apps so it can offer the 'server connection' string property and observe and capture it so that the app can set the property held on the app.

I cannot find any clear code examples.

Comment: Have you read the docs for their MDM, or checked to see if it offers an API?

Comment: I have read alot of different docs but not making much sense. Our clients use different/multiple MDM software so I am looking for a generic approach.

Comment: Do you know how to implement this?